# Arduino Nano 33 Sense won't upload

Tags: uploading

When I try to upload an example code from the Arduino_LSM9DS1 Library it either jumps ports so the upload cannot complete or spits out some red text and never completes the upload, just gets stuck on uploading.

The red text is:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:152)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:77)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:732)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:703)
    at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2047)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port 'COM5'.
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:107)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:136)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM5; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

I'm not that new to Arduino but I've never looked into uploading (I guess I should) and am struggling to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: but you can upload Blink? or did this happen after uploading the Arduino_LSM9DS1 exmple? did you try double reset to activate the bootloader?

Comment: With the bootloader active it will still sometimes jump ports either during or after uploading

Comment: yes, they do that. is is because the USB is handled by the MCU, not by a separate chip (which would not reset)

Comment: ok, so the board should be fine to use